# How to run tensor flow seq2seq demo

Tags: tensorflow

I tensor flow installed and successfully went through the MNIST demo. Now, I am trying to run the [seq2seq demo](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/index.md#), but this is not working for me.

I cloned a version of their github repo and attempted to run some of the listed commands from the repo root.

```sh
$ bazel run -c opt ./tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py 
    ERROR: Bad target pattern './tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py': package names may contain only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '/', '-' and '_'.
    INFO: Elapsed time: 0.115s
    ERROR: Build failed. Not running target.
```

No surprise here, as it doesn't really make sense to have bazel execute a python script.

Later in the tutorial,

```sh
$ bazel run -c opt //tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate \
  --data_dir ./data_dir --train_dir ./checkpoints_directory \
  --en_vocab_size=40000 --fr_vocab_size=40000

Unrecognized option: --data_dir
```

If I remove the parameters from the invocation above, it will attempt (and fail) to build the entire tensor flow project before it executes `translate`. This is not what I want as I have already successfully installed tensor flow with pip.

The last thing I tried running,

```sh
$ python ./tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.models.rnn.translate import data_utils
ImportError: No module named translate
```

Environment info: OS X 10.11.1, Python 2.7.10 (anaconda)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to run the script:

1) separate the script arguments with -- as part of bazel run

```
bazel run -c opt //tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate -- \
--data_dir ./data_dir --train_dir ./checkpoints_directory \
--en_vocab_size=40000 --fr_vocab_size=40000
```

2) build and then run from `./bazel-bin/`:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/models/rnn/translate:translate

./bazel-bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate \
--data_dir ./data_dir --train_dir ./checkpoints_directory \
--en_vocab_size=40000 --fr_vocab_size=40000
```

Comment: Thanks! Separating the script from the args with `--` is key. However, I am having various problems getting swig to build. I thought that there might be a way to run the samples w/o building since I already installed tensorflow with pip. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: The components installed with pip include models.rnn.rnn, models.rnn.rnn_cell, and models.rnn.seq2seq.

If you'd like to use your pip-installed version, one option is to avoid using bazel build/run:  modify your script to "import tensorflow as tf", "from tensorflow.models.rnn import ...."; and make the rest of the imports relative.  then run the script inside your virtualenv/python, instead of using bazel.